# Creating Python Factorial

Tags: python, factorial

Evening,

I'm an intro to python student having some trouble.
I'm trying to make a python factorial program. It should prompt the user for n and then calculate the factorial of n UNLESS the user enters -1. I'm so stuck, and the prof suggested we use the while loop. I know I didn't even get to the 'if -1' case yet. Don't know how to get python to calc a factorial with out just blatantly using the math.factorial function.

```
import math

num = 1
n = int(input("Enter n: "))

while n >= 1:
     num *= n

print(num)
```

Comment: Looks like you're almost there, I would just take it line by line.

Comment: just try some print statements inside while loop to see what is happening..

Answer (score 4):

The 'classic' factorial function in school is a recursive definition:

```
def fact(n):
    rtr=1 if n<=1 else n*fact(n-1)
    return rtr

n = int(input("Enter n: "))
print fact(n)
```

If you just want a way to fix yours:

```
num = 1
n = int(input("Enter n: "))

while n > 1:
    num *= n
    n-=1        # need to reduce the value of 'n' or the loop will not exit

print num
```

If you want a test for numbers less than 1:

```
num = 1
n = int(input("Enter n: "))

n=1 if n<1 else n    # n will be 1 or more...
while n >= 1:
    num *= n
    n-=1        # need to reduce the value of 'n' or the loop will not exit

print num
```

Or, test n after input:

```
num = 1
while True:
    n = int(input("Enter n: "))
    if n>0: break

while n >= 1:
    num *= n
    n-=1        # need to reduce the value of 'n' or the loop will not exit

print num
```

Here is a functional way using [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
>>> n=10
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, range(1,n+1))
3628800
```

Comment: we havent covered defining our own functions yet. 

the second code block is it-im really close but not quite there. how do i reference my variables in a print statement again? and is it possible to add the caveat of entering -1 with the while statement or would i need the if/then statement?


`
num = 1
n = int(input("Enter n: "))

while n > 1:
    num *= n
    n-=1
    print ("The factorial of" n "is" num)
    n = int(input("Enter n: "))
`

Comment: sorry, dont know how to add breaks in comments

Comment: Pardon me, but this is pretty horrible python, esp. the `n=1 if n<1 else n` part.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually very close.  Just update the value of `n` with each iteration:

```
num = 1
n = int(input("Enter n: "))

while n >= 1:
    num *= n
    # Update n
    n -= 1
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python and this is my factorial program.

def factorial(n):

```
x = []
for i in range(n):
    x.append(n)
    n = n-1
print(x)
y = len(x)

j = 0
m = 1
while j != y:
    m = m *(x[j])
    j = j+1
print(m)
```

factorial(5)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
    def Factorial(y):
        x = len(y)
        number = 1
        for i in range(x):
            number = number * (i + 1)
            print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Factorial using list
fact=list()
fact1=input("Enter Factorial Number:")
for i in range(1,int(fact1)+1):
    fact.append(i)
 print(fact)
 sum=fact[0]
 for j in range(0,len(fact)):
        sum*=fact[j]
        print(sum)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1
f = 1
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
if n>=0:
  while n >= i:
    f=i*f
    i+=1
  print(f)
```

I am using this code in order to calculate factorial and it works.(Python 3.8)